# prestashop 1.7 Admin login fail TypeError: jsonData is null

Tags: authentication, prestashop, admin, typeerror

Configuration prestashop 1.7.2.4

Hi everyone

I have issue after transfer site on new domain. The website is in maintenance mode. But when i try to login to Prestashop admin, i have the form i enter login and password and click to submit.

And nothing happen...

On the console i have this error log :

TypeError: jsonData is null

////// EDIT //////
MORE INFORMATION

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasErrors' of null
at Object.success (login.js?v=1.7.2.4:207)
at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
```

Someone now how can i solve it. I haven't see any solution on different forum (only for add to cart button but it's not the same issue)

Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: You should clear your browser cache, and press "Forget the password" link, and make all steps there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but...Same problem, when i click on forget password, i receive the email. i click on the link, now i have 2 fields with news email password to enter. When i enter the both, i have the same message on console (only on console) : TypeError: jsonData is null

Comment: How did it end? Have you solved it?